# Perl ForkManager child STDOUT subroutine

Tags: perl, parallel-processing, stdout, subroutine

1. The part doing the work is in a subroutine, having no knowledge
   of whether it is being invoked once or multiple times in parallel;
2. I cannot add to this subroutine.
3. The subroutine contains `print` statements.
4. The calling Perl script uses ForkManager to invoke the subroutine in parallel.
5. The STDOUT from the parallel script is, for very understandable reasons, a mess.
6. Q: What does the 'Overflow recommend?
7. I *think* that what I want is for the STDOUT from the children to be held and then dumped all at once when the child completes, giving me a STDOUT with each child's output in sequence.
8. But if I actually want something else, I trust the 'Overflow to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

```
open my $out, '>', \$output;
select($out);
...
select(STDOUT);
close($out);
print($output);
```

Comment: (It could still get intermixed with other output unless some form of locking is used.)

Comment: It blew something up. The parallel part, in the subroutine, does things like this:

Comment: Trying again: It blew something up. The parallel part, in the subroutine, does things like this:  'open(my $MASKOUT,">$outfile"); print $MASKOUT "blahblah\n";' Which now, after I added the 'select($CHILD_LOG)', results in 'print() on closed filehandle $MASKOUT'

Comment: If you get `print() on closed filehandle $MASKOUT` from that code, it's because your `open` failed. It has nothing to do with your change of the default handle used by `print`.